# Rundeck not sending emails when in Amazon VPC?

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, rundeck

I have Rundeck installed on an instance that is on a VPC in Amazon AWS. This isn't the default VPC - it is one I have created with different subnets and security groups. My issue is this: Rundeck runs and acts fine except when sending email. I get this error:

```
2014-10-01 18:05:42,758 [quartzScheduler_Worker-2] ERROR grails.app.services.rundeck.services.NotificationService - Error sending notification email to email@domain.com for Execution 109: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.0.0 HELO requires domain address . Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.0.0 HELO requires domain address
```

This is only when the instance is created in my VPC. It is in a public subnet that accesses the internet directly via an internet gateway so it has no Nat instance between it. ACLs are default for this subnet, and the security group is set to allow all outbound.

The weird thing is this works in the Amazon default VPC, but not in my created one. They are setup the exact same. Only difference is IP range obviously - both have public IPs and the security groups are setup the same. Sendmail can send email, but Java appears to not be able to.

Any ideas on what the issue is? I've tried a few things and I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with Amazon SES, but I did get it to work with Gmail smtp by using the Rundeck groovy config located here: https://gist.github.com/gschueler/5707281